# Simple replacement of init to just start console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init

On a very simple PC, I want to replace Ubuntu 12.04 /sbin/init by the most simple bash script in order to have the very minimum number of running processes. Obviously, no X, no USB, no detection of new hardware, no upgrade, no apt, "nothing", I just need a working console with a DHCP-based Wi-Fi IP address (ssid, passphrase are already stored in /etc/network/interfaces). That's all. Currently, I have tried this in replacement of /sbin/init:

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -o rw,remount /
mount -t proc none /proc
udevd --daemon
mkdir /run/network
ifup -a &
while [ 1 ]; do
    /sbin/getty -8 115200 tty1 vt100
done
```

It's working as I'm getting an IP address and I can login but:

- A) While running shutdown, I get "shutdown: Unable to shutdown system:"
- B) control-c is not working in the console
- C) After a login, I get: "bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device"
- D) After a login, I get: "bash: no job control in this shell"

Also, I have noticed that all the user-space processes have a "?" in the tty column when running ps avx. How can I fix those problems? I don't want to use upstart in order to really control what is started on the PC and have the very bare minimum.

Comment: I'm not sure if Ubuntu is the right distro to base a bare bones Linux on... isn't there a lightweight `init` that you could use instead of Upstart?

Comment: Ah: Debian still uses good old `sysvinit`. Of course, that still has runlevels and other fanciness.

Comment: @larsmans: No, Ubuntu is not the right distro to do this at all, but for a complex dependency problem, I need this distro.

Comment: I suggest you start with the server distro of Ubuntu first before you begin paring things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Busybox init. Great tiny init...

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage `runlevels` and based on your question `runlevel 3` is what you want to use.

If you have some services that you do not wish to start, you could turn them off too for that runlevel.

For booting into `runlevel 3`, you just append the boot argument to the kernel in your boot loader:

```
<EXISTING_BOOT_CMD> 3
```

If your distro uses `systemd` instead of `sysvinit`, they are instead called as `targets`. The equivalent of `runlevel 3` in `systemd` is usually named as `multi-user.target`

The kernel boot argument you would need to pass in this case is `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`

```
<EXISTING_BOOT_CMD> systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

An alternative, if you do not want to touch the boot loader:

```
systemctl enable multi-user.target
```